# Retrofit 2.4.0 with proguard

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

When  I add Retrofit 2.4.0 library to android project  >

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

and set minifyEnabled {true}

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and then add these rules to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep interface retrofit2.** { *;}
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }


-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}


-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Finally built and generated signed apk successfully but the issue is when run the  ( release apk) >  Retrofit requests not send and return { null } ..
Whats the solution Please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

maybe because of other library work with retrofit like your downloader or parser.

#### important  notice :

add rule to keep your model  classes and subjects that work with parser like :

```
-keep class com.address_package.** { *; }
```

if you use okhttp or Okhttp3  with retrofit added below rules

note :and check your parser proguard rules too

#### LIBRARY: OkHttp

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

#### okhttp3

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

Comment: Found a protobuf message but k.a.b.q had no parser() method or PARSER field. i included the proto classes in the proguard-android.txt

Comment: @LeresAldtai maybe this [sample](https://github.com/Gaket/demo_android_protobuf_simple/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro) can help you

Comment: why do you need to keep okhttp?

Comment: @c-an If you use it as a client, you need to keep  it
Otherwise, it is not necessary

Answer (score 4):

Your Proguard rules work for Retrofit, but they're also obfuscating the model classes that you use to serialize/deserialize your data. Their names are important as Retrofit/Gson matches them to do serializing/deserializing. Proguard turns them into gibberish like `a` and `b` so Retrofit/Gson cannot make sense of them.

Depending on your package setup, you need to add the following like amin mahmodi mentioned.

`-keep class your.package.name.models.** { *; }`

Answer (score 1):

**This answer may be quite late, but it could help someone else.**

Instead of keeping an entire classes with:

```
-keep class your.package.name.models.** { *; }
```

You can use:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
   @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

This would allow you to place your models anywhere you'd like and not include them in the ProGuard file as a separate rule each time you change their project location.